# DOM manipulation using JS function

Tags: javascript, function, dom

I am learning JS and very new to coding.

```js
function querySelection(e){
  console.log(document.querySelector(e));
}
querySelection('h5');
querySelection('#id');
querySelection('.className');
//querySelection('li: last child');
```

The very last query throws an error (commented). I am very new JS.I am not sure what is wrong in that query?

Comment: The correct syntax for the selector is probably `li:last-child` (i.e. no spaces)

Comment: In order to manipulate DOM you have to learn how to select things in it. And for that, you need to learn the [CSS Selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#selectors) syntax. There's no way around it, even if what you want to learn is actually JavaScript, not CSS.

Comment: The problem is that `li: last child` is not a valid [CSS selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/), you can't have a `:` with a space after it. `:` introduces pseudoclasses. At least on Chromium browsers, the error is fairly explicit about that: `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'li: last child' is not a valid selector.`. You may have meant `li:last-child`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
querySelection('li: last child');
```

to

```
querySelection('li:last-child')
```